# Error in getting java home path

Tags: django, python-2.7, neo4j

I am trying to setup neo4j. I have installed all the required packages. I wrote hello world program in neo4j

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
db = GraphDatabase("/prashant/prashant/python/neo4j")
......
```

but it throws the error `"named unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'"`

I used the python debugger on line 54 in the file `"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jpype/_linux.py"` and found that `os.getenv("JAVA_HOME")` returns `null`

but in my python shell

```
import os
os.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_11
```

Please help

Comment: Are you running your test as a different user than your script?  Double check your environment variable settings (via things like .bashrc, .bash_profile, etc).   Ensure the user that's running the neo4j code has the right setting.